# XHR vs GET (without reload)

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-places

I'm wondering if someone could help me understand how this works.

When I use AJAX (with jQuery or plain XMLHTTPRequest), I can see a request in the console labeled XHR, that's fine, I understand this.

When I try using the Google Places Autocomplete, and I monitor the requests in the console they're not labeled as *XHR* but *GET*. You may see it [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete) - try the autocomplete search and see the requests in the console.

Are those AJAX requests too? If so, why aren't they labeled as *XHR*? If not, how is it being handled? Is a plain GET faster than XHR?

Comment: they're probably actually using jsonp, which isn't sent as an xhr request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Screen grab]

The responses are scripts. They are using [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) which is a hack used to work around the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) which was commonly used before [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) was introduced.

> Are those AJAX requests too? If so, why aren't they labeled as XHR?

They are Ajax requests, but they work by injecting `<script>` elements into the page instead of using `XMLHttpRequest`.

> Is a plain GET faster than XHR?

A GET request is a GET request. It doesn't matter if it is initiated by injecting a `<script>` element or using XHR. The HTTP request is still the same.